# SourceTree permanent local discard

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to Sourcetree and source control in general.  I am working on an Android project with a few other people and use bitbucket as the repository.  I have learned the basics but don't want to track certain files in my local, specifically a lot of the gradle and iml files.  But i think Stop tracking will remove those from the repo.  Is there a way to just have source tree ignore any changes i make to certain files locally but not delete them from the repo ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file and name it `.gitignore` in the root of the project and in that file place every directory to exclude by git like:

```
my_folder
my_folder2
```

The above would be excluded from git tracked files.

If you are already tracking files this command will remove them from index:

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

Comment: that didn't work for me.  I researched that and it said that once you start tracking the files .gitignore won't work.  However, the issue with not tracking them is I believe it removes them from the repo which is what I am trying not to do.  Any other ideas ?

Comment: Updated answer.